# How To Force EF-CodeFirst To Ignore Creating Existing Views?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've a `View` in my existing database which is completely created by **EF-CodeFirst**, Now I've added `View`'s `Entity` but when I run my application it throws an exception says `There is already an object named 'View' in the database`. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you instead create code based migration and replace `CreateTable<YourEntity>` and all related `AddColumn` calls with `Sql` call creating your view (your view must not exist in the database)?

Comment: Its you Ladislav The GOD of EntityFramework :P ;),Can you explain how should I do that? I'm not so familiar with migration in EF-CodeFirst.

Comment: Are you using automatic migrations? To make yourselves more familiar with migrations check the link provided by @ZackT in his comment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using automatic migration,thanks currently I'm reading that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation of what is happening:** 
You are getting this error because the database already has an object (view or table, etc) called "View" and EF-Code First with migrations is attempting to create it again.

When you run your application, EF Code First looks in the database for a dbo.__MigrationHistory table (usually found in System Tables).  This table keeps track of what migrations have been ran.  Look in this table to see if migrations are creating it and populating it correctly.

**Answer for you:**
Ensure that you are using migrations and EF-code first correctly.  If you can, try deleting the existing View (or table) and let EF create it again.  At that point, if you have migrations set up correctly, your migration table should "upgrade" itself using migrations and have that entry in the MigrationHistory table.

Comment: Yes I'm using migration, but another question expose based on what you've explained, Is there a specific way to create View in EF-CodeFirst? Because I create Views in database manually.

Comment: I added a class to my model, and used the information from the [Generating & Running Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) section of the Entity Framework Code First Migrations article in the Data Developer Center to be able to update the database with a new table.